# How do I confirm that I don't have duplicate classes within my ClassLoader structure?

Tags: java, groovy, groovyclassloader

I'm using a GroovyClassLoader to load multiple groovy files (not scripts) that have Class names and package structures. I believe I'm running into an issue of multiple Class files being loaded for the same Class, despite calling parseClass only once per file based on this type of error message:

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'TickIt.Pizza@3eea9be9' with class 'TickIt.Pizza' to class 'TickIt.Pizza'

Additionally, I have some instances where I use a Static setter for storing a variable, and calling the Class implicitly seems to indicate there are additional copies of the Class since after setting the variable I can reference it and it seems to be empty.

I've made a small test to attempt to prove the problem, and it seems to indicate that indeed there are multiple Classes loaded. By finding the matching Class in loadedClasses on my GroovyClassLoader, I can compare to the implicit Class. For my DockingBay Class, I have a static Map called shuttles. The loaded class of DockingBay has value, but implicitly calling Dockingbay.shuttles comes up empty. See below:

```
DockingBay:   ${ DockingBay.classLoader } <br>
              ${ DockingBay.shuttles } <br>
Loaded:       ${ PartsStore.groovyClassLoader.loadedClasses[28].classLoader } <br>
              ${ PartsStore.groovyClassLoader.loadedClasses[28].shuttles }<br>

Are they the same?: ${ PartsStore.groovyClassLoader.loadedClasses.contains(DockingBay) }
```

Output:

```
DockingBay: groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@6bc407fd 
[:] 
Loaded: groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@4b79ac84 
[class hudelements.HudElements:hudelements.HudElements@4f936da8, class TickIt.PizzaShop:TickIt.PizzaShop@e041f0c, class calc.Calc:calc.Calc@6a175569, class monitor.Monitor:monitor.Monitor@69c79f09]

Are they the same?: false
```

Here's my code that loads my files to the GroovyClassLoader, which I call PartsStore.

```
boolean hasLoaded = false
GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader
loadedClasses = []

public scan() {

    if (hasLoaded) { 
        println('Purging groovyClassLoader Meta.')
        for (def clazz in groovyClassLoader.loadedClasses)
            GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(clazz)

        println('Clearing groovyClassLoader Cache.')
        groovyClassLoader.clearCache()

    } else {
        println('Creating new groovyClassLoader.')
        groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(Spaceport.class)
    }

    hasLoaded = true

    for (String path in Spaceport.config.modules.'class paths') {
        File dir = new File(path)
        groovyClassLoader.addClasspath(dir.getAbsolutePath())
    }

    def errors = false

    for (String path in Spaceport.config.modules.'include paths') {
        // Get directory listing
        println('+ -> ' + path)
        File[] directoryListing = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(path), null, false)
        // Load all .groovy files
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(child.getName()) == 'groovy') {
                    try {
                        println 'Loading include "' + child + '"'
                        groovyClassLoader.parseClass(child))
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        errors = true
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect no matter where I call my class DockingBay from (provided it's loaded on the same GroovyClassLoader), I would receive the same Class that is loaded in the ClassLoader. It seems I am not. I noticed that comparing the classLoaders of the Classes shows they are different (but consistent) InnerLoaders. Why?